# Reboot Android 5.x with no user apps (Facebook etc.) opened

Tags: nexus-7

I have a Google Nexus 7 tablet of the first generation. I just use it occasionally and turn it off, when unused.

With Android 4.x I always got a cleanly booted system, without any user app opened (like Facebook, Stack Exchange App, News Apps etc.).
It increases booting time immense and bothers me a lot.

**Is there any way to get the old starting behavior of Android 4.x back?**

On a desktop PC I'd say I'd like to have a **Shut down**, but my tablet behaves like **sleep** since Android 5.0, even when turning it off.

Comment: Are they already running after a device restart and you had manually closed them or not?

Comment: @Ramhound I deleted that sentence, it just worked now, when I closed the apps before. It's still not the desired behaviour.